# Compiling MPI/VTK Hello World

Tags: c++, ubuntu, command-line, mpi, vtk

I downloaded VTK 6.0.0, configured it, generated it, and made it in my Ubuntu 12.04 (with no errors). I also turned on the flag for `VTK_Group_MPI` and `Module_vtkmrmpi`. I am trying to compile a VTK/MPI Hello World program using the command line

```
sudo mpic++ -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK6.0.0Attempt2/Parallel/MPI mpi_vtk_Hello_World.cpp -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK6.0.0Attempt2/Parallel/Core -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK6.0.0Attempt2/Common/Core -o mpi_vtk_Hello_World
```

The Hello world program is:

```
#include "vtkMPIController.h" 

void process(vtkMultiProcessController* controller, void* vtkNotUsed(arg)) 
{ 
    int myId = controller->GetLocalProcessId(); 

    std::cout << "My process id is "; 
    std::cout << myId << "." << std::endl; 
} 

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{ 
    vtkMPIController* controller = vtkMPIController::New(); 
    controller->Initialize(&argc, &argv); 


    controller->SetSingleMethod(process, 0); 
    controller->SingleMethodExecute(); 


    controller->Finalize(); 
    controller->Delete(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

However, I get an error saying that:

```
/tmp/cc6iq2lQ.o:mpi_vtk_Hello_World.cpp:function process(vtkMultiProcessController*, void*): error: undefined reference to 'vtkMultiProcessController::GetLocalProcessId()'
```

along with 2 other similar errors of undefined references.

I am not entirely sure why these errors are occurring. I was thinking it may be because of the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX parameter, but it made correctly. I was also thinking I may be using the wrong flags to enable MPI, as suggested [here](http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/50zHj1hYwwTAT06EeG4o).

**Additional notes:** 
I also tried using VTK 5.8.0 instead and followed [these instructions](http://wwwx.cs.unc.edu/Research/bass/index.php/VTK). Unfortunately, I got the same errors of undefined references after running the `sudo mpicc++` command.

Comment: You should link the VTK library with your program, e.g. by providing the correct link option to the compile command like `-lvtk`.

Comment: I tried doing **sudo mpic++ -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK/Parallel -lvtk mpi_vtk_Hello_World.cpp -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK/Common -o mpi_vtk_Hello_World**

 but I got an error that 

**/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lvtk**. I don't appear to have a libvtk.so, but I do have a bunch of other ones libvtk*.so

Comment: Never mind, I tried using `-lvtkParallel`, and it seemed to work. How would I know these command line link options though?

Comment: By reading the manual?

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the manual discussing about those options like `-lvtk` and `-lvtkParallel`? I'm not sure what manual you're referring to. I went to http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.8/html/index.html and tried the search and wiki, but I only found scattered examples.

Comment: Now that you've figured out the solution, add it as an answer to this question and accept it so posterity will be able to find it on Google and have a slightly easier time of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo mpic++ -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK/Parallel -lvtkParallel mpi_vtk_Hello_World.cpp -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK -I $HOME/Downloads/VTK/Common -o mpi_vtk_Hello_World
```

works. Apparently `-lvtkParallel` was needed to help compile the mpi/VTK code.